# grep exclude-dir in current directory or subdirectories

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm attempting to setup my `GREP_OPTIONS` to always exclude certain directories (e.g. `target/classes`).  I'm specifically trying to get this to work for recursive greps.  Using `--exclude-dir=target/classes` works great when the current directory contains `target/classes`, but not so when I'm in the parent directory.  My current solution requires me to set both `--exclude-dir=target/classes` and `--exclude-dir=*/target/classes`.  I'm looking for a more direct solution, which I assume will involve a regex.  I've tried `--exclude-dir=(*/)?target/classes` and other permutations, but I can't get it to work.

Yes yes, I'm sure this can be accomplished with other tools (i.e. find, awk, etc), but I'd really like to keep this confined (if possible) to the `GREP_OPTIONS` solution.

Comment: The info page for grep seems to indicate that the argument to `--exclude-dir` is a `GLOB`. Globs can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example tested, be careful with syntax and not to typo:

```
root/dspace# grep -r --exclude-dir={log,assetstore} "creativecommons.org"
```

Above i grep for text "creativecommons.org" in current directory "dspace" and exclude dirs {log,assetstore}.

Done.